# Could Dark Matter imply the existence of Dark energy?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, dark-matter, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

This is admittedly a simple example, but it seems to check out. Consider the standard metric for the Schwarzschild solution in coordinates $(t, r,\theta,\phi)$:

$$ g_{oo} = U, \ g_{11} = V, \ g_{22} = r^2, \ g_{33} = r^2\sin^2(\theta) $$

with the energy tensor representing a point particle with 0 momentum or stresses: $$T^{00} = m_{\text{rel}} \ \text{and} \ T^{\mu\neq 0 \nu\neq 0} = 0$$.

If one now adds an arbitrary dark matter gravity term such that $g_{00} = U + \Omega_t(r)$ and $g_{1} = V + \Omega_r(r)$, but restricts $T^{00}$ to remain constant, the conservation law of the energy tensor will pick up cross terms. Here $\Omega_r$ and $\Omega_t$ are strictly functions of $r$ and not $t$.

To begin, the Christoffel symbols are:
$$\Gamma^0_{ik} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{U'+\Omega_t'}{2(U+\Omega_t)} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{U'+\Omega_t'}{2(U+\Omega_t)} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$

$$\Gamma^1_{ik} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-(U'+\Omega_t')}{2(V+\Omega_r)} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{V' + \Omega_r'}{2(V + \Omega_r)} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{-r}{V+\Omega_r} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-r\sin^2(\theta)}{V+\Omega_r} \end{bmatrix},$$

$$\Gamma^2_{ik} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{r} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{r} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix},$$

$$\Gamma^3_{ik} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{r} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cot(\theta) \\ 0 & \frac{1}{r} & \cot(\theta) & 0  \end{bmatrix},$$

and for later purposes:

$$\Gamma^k_{ik} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{U'+\Omega_t'}{2(U+\Omega_t)} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{V' + \Omega_r'}{2(V + \Omega_r)} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{r} & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & \frac{1}{r} & \cot(\theta) & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

We will now utilize the following conservation law:
$$0 = \nabla_\nu T^{\mu\nu} = \partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu} + \Gamma^\mu_{\sigma\nu} T^{\sigma\nu} + \Gamma^{\nu}_{\sigma\nu} T^{\mu\sigma}.$$

Before going through, we restrict $T^{\mu\nu}$ to the following:
$$T^{\mu\nu} = \begin{bmatrix} m_\text{rel} & p^r & 0 & 0 \\ p^r & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Furthermore, all derivatives of $T^{\mu\nu}$ by an angular component are taken to be zero. Doing so gives:

$$\partial_i T^{0i} + \Gamma^{0}_{\sigma\nu}T^{\sigma\nu} + \Gamma^\nu_{\sigma\nu} T^{0\sigma} = 0 $$

$$\partial_t m_\text{rel} + \partial_r p^r + \frac{U'+\Omega_t'}{2(U+\Omega_t)}p^r + \left( \frac{U'+\Omega_t'}{2(U+\Omega_t)} + \frac{V' + \Omega_r'}{2(V + \Omega_r)} + \frac{2}{r} \right)p^r = 0 $$

$$\partial_t m_\text{rel} + \partial_r p^r + \left( \frac{U'+\Omega_t'}{U+\Omega_t} + \frac{V' + \Omega_r'}{2(V + \Omega_r)} + \frac{2}{r} \right)p^r = 0 $$

and

$$\partial_i T^{1i} + \Gamma^{1}_{\sigma\nu}T^{\sigma\nu} + \Gamma^\nu_{\sigma\nu} T^{1\sigma} = 0 $$

$$\partial_t p^r - \frac{(U'+\Omega_t')}{2(V+\Omega_r)} m_\text{rel} = 0 $$

From the $\mu = 1$ equations we get

$$p^r = \frac{(U'+\Omega_t')}{2(V+\Omega_r)} m_\text{rel} t + C(r),$$

which, regardless of additional manipulation, already starts to hint at some properties of dark matter and energy. From the $\mu = 0$ equations, with the assumption that $\partial_t m_\text{rel} = 0$, we get the differential equation:

$$\frac{\partial_r p^r}{p^r} = \left( \frac{U'+\Omega_t'}{U+\Omega_t} + \frac{V' + \Omega_r'}{2(V + \Omega_r)} + \frac{2}{r} \right)$$

$$p^r = \exp \left( \int \frac{U'+\Omega_t'}{U+\Omega_t} + \frac{V' + \Omega_r'}{2(V + \Omega_r)} + \frac{2}{r} \, dr \right) + C(t)$$

Together, the most most general form for the momentum as a function of 'time' and radius is:

$$p^r = \exp \left( \int \frac{U'+\Omega_t'}{U+\Omega_t} + \frac{V' + \Omega_r'}{2(V + \Omega_r)} + \frac{2}{r} \, dr \right) + \frac{(U'+\Omega_t')}{2(V+\Omega_r)} m_\text{rel}t  + C$$

We note that while the functions $\Omega_t$ and $\Omega_r$ can arbitrarily alter $U$ and $V$ to fit dark matter curves, if $\frac{U' +\Omega_t'}{2(V+\Omega_r)}$ is strictly positive beyond a certain radius, the momentum can increase infinitely.

Ultimately, this just shows that Dark Matter and Energy could be connected by a single set of functions, rather than as operating independently from one another.

Looking at the formula, I worry about variance in the momentum between reference frames that doesn't fit nicely into the equivalence principle....

Is my line of reasoning correct? If so is this preferable to current ideas of DM and DE in any meaningful way?

P.S. We all hate the nitty gritty of christoffel symbols and coordinate expressions so if I made a mistake let me know :D. Also I could very well have made other more fundamental mistakes in my process I'm not really at the 'advanced' level for GR.

Comment: "Looking at the formula, I worry..."- why so?? Besides, for calculating tensor components like Christoffel, Einstein, Ricci tensors you can use exclusive packages.. like I use GREAT.m package in mathematica to directly calculate all these stuffs

Comment: @KP99 My main concern is the invertibility of the exponential. Since exponentials are strictly positive one could imagine difficulties in some tranformation $r \rightarrow r' =-1r$. I haven't explored it much though

Comment: The radial component $p^r$ should be $\sim \:(p_0)^r.exp(..)+..$. Although exp is strictly positive, the overall constant factor of $(p_0)^r$ should determine the sign of momentum

Comment: @KP99 oh that seems obvious now thanks XD

Comment: Ok, so what is the actual question?

Comment: I guess just wondering if my line of reasoning makes sense. Basically "is this true?/does this work?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some general observations: if we ignore the test particle for the moment (i.e. $T_{00}=0$), then the form of Stress Energy tensor in this case will satisfy the Hawking-Ellis (Segre-Plebanski) type IV geometry (more about this here: https://inspirehep.net/literature/619666 ). Such types of stress energy tensor doesn't correspond to any known source of classical stress energy, instead they are more relevant for quantum fields. So, we will need a quantum field Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_M$ which can give a physical picture behind the metric perturbations $\Omega_t(r)$ and $\Omega_r(r)$. Such a field can be a potential candidate for dark matter if it can explain observational evidences as summarized in  http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4005 .

Dark energy is used to explain cosmological constant in standard $\Lambda$- CDM cosmology. However, this "dark energy" can have a different origin altogether. For instance in inhomogeneous cosmological models, an additional back-reaction term due to imperfection in general fluid $T_{\mu\nu}$ can give a physical picture of dark energy effects (see : https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1001800617177 )

Comment: I may be wrong, but because what I've written is fairly general $\Omega_r$ and $\Omega_t$ could probably be altered to include interacting fields so as to align with $\Lambda$CDM. I wouldn't consider that an 'elegant' solution, per say, but it could be viable.

Comment: @iglizworks There can be different classes of solutions, not just this particular form of metric. The point is, you will also need to give a physical interpretation of what is actually giving rise to such a metric. One can always propose some arbitrary form of metric, but it may not have any physical significance

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. Thankyou for the feedback